# Messaging App using MQTT

Tags: android, messaging, mqtt

I am trying to create a android messaging app using MQTT.
But i just want to know how the existing messaging apps(based on MQTT) work?

I am think of creating a unique topic for each user who installs and setups the app for the first time (providing his mobile no/email id for his topic to receive messages from others).

Once the setup is completed the contacts from users device will be synced with my server to check the available users.

And finally the user can select from the available contacts to send messages(publish messages based on the selected contacts mobile no or email id).

I know we should encrypt the contacts to protect the users privacy but,
Am i going in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is way too broad to get a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Typically you set up a topic like
appName/device/*[deviceID]*
you could then put additional topics under that, like
appName/device/*[deviceId]*/contacts/*contactName*

You would then create authorization rules that limit a device to only publish things to appName/device/*[deviceId]*/# for the specific device id.

You could do a topic like appName/device/*[deviceI]*/contacts/online to get a list of available contacts... and a reply topic that gave back the results.

Comment: MQTT topics do not start with a leading / and the wildcard is either a # or + not a *

Comment: Would this be true even if the user publishes a file, say an image or PDF?